# Is it possible to using Type Inference for the first parameter and specify another type

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, extension-methods, type-inference

This is a simple contrived example, but hopefully will illustrate my query.

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name = "test";
}


public static class Ext 
{
     public static Test ConvertToTest<T1>(this T1 source) 
     {
         return new Test();
     }

     public static T2 Convert<T1,T2>(this T1 source) where T2 : new()
     {
         return new T2();
     }
}
```

ConvertToTest only needs one Type, so the following compile

```
    Ext.ConvertToTest<string>("hello");
    "hello".ConvertToTest();
```

The last uses type-interfence and this means it also works with anonymous classes, eg

```
    var anon = (new { Name = "test" }) ;
    anon.ConvertToTest();
```

However this is hardcoded to always use the class Test, whereas I want to be able to specify the type as in the second method

I can write

```
   Ext.Convert<string, Test>("hello");
```

and this compiles, because I know both types at compile time, but I can't use it with anonymous classes, and I can't find a way of using type-inference plus the extra Type

It would be nice if I could do something like

```
    anon.Convert<,Test>()  ;
```

and the compiler would know to use inference for the first type (which isn't specified) and use Test as the second type.

Is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking on a single method, but if you're clever and willing to define a couple of different classes you should be able to make syntax like this possible:

```
var test = Ext.Convert("hello").To<Test>();
```

Just make `Convert` be based on a single generic type, and have it return a generic type based on that:

```
public Converter<T> Convert<T>(T source)
{
    return new Converter<T>(source);
}
```

Then add a method to the type it returns which serves as a basic wrapper for your original method:

```
public class Converter<T>
{
    T _source;
    internal Converter(T source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }
    public T2 To<T2>()
    {
        return Ext.Convert<T, T2>(_source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Dunno about being clever, but I guess I am clever enough to cut and paste as I have got this working. I think there are a few syntax errors, eg Converter<T> class should not inherit from itself and the last line should use _source instead of source. And I changed the definition of Convert to  public static Converter<T> Convert<T>(this T source), so that I can use it as an extension method.

Comment: @sgmoore: Hehe, sometimes it takes a clever person just to wade through my hastily-thrown-together code. That's a good idea with the extension method, btw.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do what you want. You use a template pattern - it's a little bit of a kludge but it allows you to infer both types. It can also be use to infer anonymous types.

Here it is:

```
public static T2 Convert<T1,T2>(this T1 source, Func<T2> template)
    where T2 : new()
{
    return new T2();
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var anon = (new { Name = "test" }) ;
anon.Convert(() => new Test());
```

Which isn't too far from your pseudo-code.